# C#: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll in a connection pool slow

Tags: c#, oracle, pool

C#: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll in a connection pool slow: Here is the scenario:
App starts up. We send a request that needs to fetch the data from oracle DB. At this time the pool is initiated and all other stuff happens behind the scenes. Data is returned in 2 seconds. When I send more requests simultaneously the data is returned in 100 to 200 ms. Now when the application gets another request after 45 secs of inactivity, data is returned in over 1.5 secs, however simultaneous bursts of requests is responded within 150 ms. App and DB are on the same server.

Some Settings in the connect descriptor:
Max Pool Size: 10 
Min Pool Size: 5
Connection Timeout: 60
Connection Lifetime: 60

Any ideas of why the delay after first query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it the same SQL call to the database on every call? How are you reading the data (data reader, data table, ORM)?  Can you show some example code / SQL / Schema?  Do you have indexes on the table that are being used?

Comment: Yes. It is the same SQL call. We pass a employee ID to the stored proc and get the First and Last Name and the indexes are properly setup. Issue is always with the first read. Unfortunately I don't have access to the code to show.

Comment: After the first call, Oracle caches the results (especially of an index lookup) so any identical calls that come after it will execute MUCH faster.  Try to change the query on every call and see if you get the same timing results.  Every different call should be closer to the first call time wise.  If that is the case, and you still need it faster, you will need to post at least some similar SQL code to what you have to get real help.

Comment: Call is same. However the lookup data will be different all the time.